# Ionic Cordova OpenTok can't publish video from IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, webrtc, opentok

I am trying to implement OpenTok on a ionic application and I can't publish videos from an iphone.
Subscribing from videos work (I can run the app on my computer and publish a video, which I can see on my iphone), but viceversa it does not work.

I have the following settings in my config.xml

```
        <config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>This app needs to access your camera in order to take a profile photo or save a photo in the files or messages section.</string>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="NSMicrophoneUsageDescription" target="*-Info.plist">
            <string>This app needs to access your microphone in order to record videos that you can upload in the files or messages section.</string>
        </config-file>
```

And also, I am using this code:

```
    startCall() {
        this.session = OT.initSession(this.apiKey, this.sessionId);
        this.publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher');

        this.session.on({
            streamCreated: (event: any) => {
                this.session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber');
                OT.updateViews();
            },
            streamDestroyed: (event: any) => {
                console.log(`Stream ${event.stream.name} ended because ${event.reason}`);
                OT.updateViews();
            },
            sessionConnected: (event: any) => {
                this.session.publish(this.publisher);
            }
        });

        this.session.connect(this.token, (error: any) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(`There was an error connecting to the session ${error}`);
            }
        });
    }
```

I added some console.logs and it enters session.on sessionConnected and also session.connect, with no other errors, so I dont understand what could be happening

Thanks

Comment: Facing same issue. Did you find out something to resolve this?

Comment: Not really .. for now I am sending the users from the application to the website version of the project (where I also have opentok) .. and I hope I'll be able to implement it on the app soon

Comment: Try upgrading the opentok plugin to 3.4.3

Comment: This worked for you ?

Comment: yes exactly. Upgrading helped me there

Answer (score 1):

This is because the cordova openTok plugin is not in sync with the latest iOS SDK it points to 2.15.5 but the latest is 2.17.4. So you can try to point the version.
For a quick test, I updated the plugin and you can test if this works for you. You can add the plugin like in config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-opentok" spec="github:neerajpathak77/cordova-plugin-opentok" />
```

Which will result in the below in package.json

```
"cordova-plugin-opentok": "github:neerajpathak77/cordova-plugin-opentok",
```

Now, this should work for you.

One more way you can try to test is you can open the YourProject.xcworkspace file in Xcode and then open Podfile file and add the below line to pod file
(Attention: we are changing the generated files so each time we run cordova platform add ios these changes will be gone)

```
pod 'OpenTok 2.17.0'
```

then run command

```
pod install
```

In case of error change target to the latest one in your pod file

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

Hope it helps